# When to use attributes in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to learn to convert a XML file to XSD. I am reading and seeing some tutorials on the internet, but I didn't find out when I have to use attributes in the XSD. If I fx have this XML file:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/books"/>
<catalog>
    <book id="book_1">
        <author>Dave Winer</author>
        <title>Learn XML</title>
        <genre>IT Science</genre>
        <publish_date>1999-03-03</publish_date>
        <price>30</price>
        <description>A insight in the XML world</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

I have tried to write the XSD file. Does it looks correct, or do I need some attributes to? In case why and when do I have to use it?

Best Regards From Julie

```
<xs:element name="catalog">
    <xs:complexType>
        <sequence>
            <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="genre" type="string"/>
            <xs:element name="publish_date" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        </sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are some errors. For example, the `<sequence>` element should be `<xs:sequence>` and the type attributes should also use the `xs` prefix: `<xs:string>` and `<xs:decimal>`.

I guess you also want to declare the `id` attribute, and probably it should be a required, unique identity. So, this schema is what you want:

EDIT: When I looked at it again, I realized that what I wrote is wrong and does not capture the XML example you gave (the book element was missing):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="catalog">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="publish_date" type="xs:date" />
                        <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
                        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The `<xs:attribute>` declaration is needed to allow for `id` attribute on the `<book>` element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and a very good answer. Just one last question. So the line:  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required" /> means that each book has to get an id, and it is required to have a name, right ?

Answer (score 0):

@forty-two already provided a [good review](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482712/366749) of your XSD.

To answer specifically on the use of attributes, usually you can follow the very same principles that apply to modeling data structures.
Attributes are appropriate to consider (over child elements) for:

- information that really "defines" or "belongs" to the structure
- information that is represented by a simple type (complex type are obviously better modeled as child elements)
- information whose cardinality is really 1:1 (i.e. if multiple values are possible, then again it's obviously better as a child-element)
- information where a default value is usually appropriate (preferred or implied)

Of course, reading the whole [primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#PO) is a good idea to see decently concrete examples of content models.

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot for your supplying answer :-) thanks a lot.